# Javascript assets not loading on production server with nginx and puma

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma

My js in loading on server I am using rails 7 with ruby 3 and puma with nginx

this is my server log and it is not find main.js file and I am not sure what this main.js file is which is not finding, my js files are named inside app/assets/js active_admin.js application.js owl.carousel.min.js

and in `app/javascripts >> application.js and in app/javascripts/controllers >> application.js hello_controller.js index.js my_controller.js`

I have tried doing assets:clobber and then assets:precompile and then tried setting

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

this is the log I am getting in my production

```
 I, [2023-09-25T09:20:39.578671 #261785]  INFO -- : [a08fa8fd-a703-469f-b846-5fe6cbb7a098] Started GET "/services/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-09-25 09:20:39 +0000
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:39.582762 #261785]  INFO -- : [a08fa8fd-a703-469f-b846-5fe6cbb7a098] Processing by ServicesController#new as HTML
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:39.620643 #261785]  INFO -- : [a08fa8fd-a703-469f-b846-5fe6cbb7a098]   Rendered services/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 37.1ms | Allocations: 6446)
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:39.622622 #261785]  INFO -- : [a08fa8fd-a703-469f-b846-5fe6cbb7a098]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 39.1ms | Allocations: 7658)
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:39.623055 #261785]  INFO -- : [a08fa8fd-a703-469f-b846-5fe6cbb7a098] Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 39.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms | Allocations: 7923)
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:41.408520 #261785]  INFO -- : [feda6a42-adfa-443f-a4ef-541d7d55b836] Started GET "/services/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-09-25 09:20:41 +0000
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:41.411611 #261785]  INFO -- : [962b6dd3-4fdf-485c-b706-881990a91d0a] Started GET "/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-09-25 09:20:41 +0000
F, [2023-09-25T09:20:41.417244 #261785] FATAL -- : [962b6dd3-4fdf-485c-b706-881990a91d0a]   
[962b6dd3-4fdf-485c-b706-881990a91d0a] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"):
[962b6dd3-4fdf-485c-b706-881990a91d0a]   
I, [2023-09-25T09:20:41.413967 #261785]  INFO -- : [a7579a7f-71e8-4130-9dcf-0986fe4e1ed2] Started GET "/services/js/main.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-09-25 09:20:41 +0000
F, [2023-09-25T09:20:41.423796 #261785] FATAL -- : [a7579a7f-71e8-4130-9dcf-0986fe4e1ed2]   
[a7579a7f-71e8-4130-9dcf-0986fe4e1ed2] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/js/main.js"):
[a7579a7f-71e8-4130-9dcf-0986fe4e1ed2]   
F, [2023-09-25T09:20:41.420025 #261785] FATAL -- : [feda6a42-adfa-443f-a4ef-541d7d55b836]   
[feda6a42-adfa-443f-a4ef-541d7d55b836] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"):
[feda6a42-adfa-443f-a4ef-541d7d55b836]
```

Comment: what is the path of your linked assets in the html? are you starting your links with a slash? `/path/to/assets/script.js`?

Comment: what do you mean by linked assets? I don't understand I have production and development two modes, I am using ec2 and In ec2 I have this `ubuntu@ip-ip-my-ip-ad:/var/www/html$ ls
index.html  index.nginx-debian.html` and I am working in directory inside `ubuntu@ip-Mm-ip-ad:/var/www/myapp/current$`

Comment: how is this resource `owl.carousel.min.js` linked in your html page? It has to be somewhere, something like `<script src="/path/to/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>`, right?

Comment: In my development mode It is inside `app/assets/javascripts >> active_admin.js application.js owl.carousel.min.js`

Comment: when you open this: `/services/new` could you please look at the page source, find "owl.carousel.min.js" and post the entire line, which should be something like `<script src="/path/to/something/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: inside my home page html page i tried defining them explicitly as 

`<script src="/assets/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">`

Comment: your app error states this path was not found: `/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js`, I can't really see any directory named `lib` in your snippets.

Comment: I do have a lib folder that doesn't contain anything related to JS